# ignore non-ajax requests to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want that action was available only to performance at the request of object of XHR. As I tried it to realize:
In the controller there is an action:

```
      public string Act()
        {     
         string view="";
        if(Request.Headers["p"]!="p")
            Response.Redirect("/",true);
        else
            view = GetActView();

        return view;
        }
```

It is caused by means of onclick of an event to which function is attached:

```
       function updateDiv() { 
               xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById('actdiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            } 
            }
           xmlhttp.open('GET', '/Act', true);
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("p", "p");
          xmlhttp.send();                
         }
```

But in addition to request from this function I can address to action, having collected in an address line of the browser website.com/Act value. This inadmissible behavior of my site. How to prevent such action of the user correctly ?

Comment: You can't reliably do this. The better option is to design the application so accessing the action via the address bar is ok.

Comment: And how then do in such cases for SPA?

Comment: @JohnStiks We do implement security features using multiple approaches. One is in my answer, second is using `AntiForgeryToken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that in the controller action using `Request.IsAjaxRequest`.For your action it can be done as below:

```
public string Act()
{     
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest)
    {
      //AJAX work or response
    }
   //Non-AJAX work

}
```

You can even write a custom Attribute for this as below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
            if (result != null && result.Model != null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = result.Model,
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can be applied on the controller method just like other ffilters as below:

```
[AjaxOnly]
public string Act()
{     


}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this can be faked, and shouldn't be relied upon for purposes of security.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by changing your request to 'POST' instead of 'GET'. Then the action should be decorated with [HttpPost] attribute like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Act()
{     
}
```